# Assets\Scripts\InGamePanel.cs(6,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hi i get this errors using unity
1 ==> Assets\Scripts\InGamePanel.cs(6,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

2 ==> Assets\Scripts\InGamePanel.cs(110,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

the script :

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

{
    private void Start()
    {
        bool interstitialsDisabled = LvlBtnHandler.activeStage > 0 && LvlBtnHandler.activeLevel > 0 && StageModel.IsFirstStage(LvlBtnHandler.activeStage) && !GameState.Instance.HasLevelAccess(StageModel.GetSecondStageId(), 1) && !StageModel.IsLastLevel();
        //LionAdManager.Instance.SetInterstitialsDisabled(interstitialsDisabled);
        Button[] componentsInChildren = base.GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();
        componentsInChildren[2].onClick.AddListener(new UnityAction(this.ShowHomeModal));
    }

    private void Update()
    {
    }
    

    private void Exit()
    {
        UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(this.modal);
    }

     

    public void ShowHomeModal()
    {
        GameObject gameObject = GameObject.Find("NewCanvas02");
        this.modal = UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate<GameObject>(Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/HomeModal"), gameObject.transform);
        Button[] componentsInChildren = this.modal.GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();
        componentsInChildren[0].onClick.AddListener(new UnityAction(this.Exit));
        componentsInChildren[1].onClick.AddListener(new UnityAction(this.Menu));
        componentsInChildren[2].onClick.AddListener(new UnityAction(this.Exit));
    }

    public void Menu()
    {
        //if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name != "Customization" && !AFtitle.noAds && LionAdManager.Instance.IsTimeToShowIntersitial() && LvlBtnHandler.activeStage != 0)
        {
            AFtitle.watchedReward = false;
            //LionAdManager.Instance.MaybeShowInterstitial();
        }
        //if (AppLovinCrossPromo.Instance() != null)
        //{
        //  AppLovinCrossPromo.Instance().HideMRec();
        //}
        if (LvlBtnHandler.activeStage == 0)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
        }
        PlayerBF.jumped = false;
        PlayerBF.land = false;
        PlayerBF.fallen = false;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("NewLvlSelect");
    }

    public void NextStage()
    {
        LvlBtnHandler.activeStage++;
        LvlBtnHandler.activeLevel = 1;
    string[] array = new string[]
    {
            string.Empty,
            "GymNew",
            "MountNew",
            "City",
            "House",
            "Gallery",
            "Ship"
    };
        SceneManager.LoadScene(array[LvlBtnHandler.activeStage]);
    }

    private void GameOver()
    {
        this.gameOverPanel.SetActive(true);
        base.Invoke("Restart", 2f);
    }

    public void LevelCompleted()
    {
        this.lvlCompletePanel.SetActive(true);
        GameObject.Find("Score").GetComponent<Score>().SetTotalScore();
        GameObject.Find("Score").GetComponent<Score>().FinishedLevel();
}


    public GameObject gameOverPanel();

    public GameObject lvlCompletePanel();

private GameObject modal();

}
```

please any help for this issue i get this problem for many times

Comment: you are missing your namespace declaration

Comment: You didn’t define a class you just opened a bracket and let rip

Comment: BugFinder you want to say that to introduce bracket after start update and exit classes or what  could you please explain more

Answer (score 1):

You cannot code methods in the global namespace directly. These need to go inside a class.
If you want Start() and Update() you need it to derive from monobehaviour. Put your code inside this trial class and name it as you wish. Remember the name of the script should be the same of the class with .cs, for this class for example should be TrialClass.cs, so that you can attach scripts to gameobjects.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TrialClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```